Implement findObjectsNearLocation() function using JpaRepository
so I have my Spring Project using Postgres SQL. The project has an entity called "Object" which includes a property named "Location" (Which will be shown below).
What I'm trying to do is method called:
List<ObjectEntity> findObjectsNearLocation(double lat, double lng, double radius);
in Object logic crud which takes a point and a radius distance and gets all the Objects that have a location within that radius (Red zone in the image below).

I already found sql queries online but I'm trying to avoid using them. I also found something called GeoResult. Is there any way using built-in method from JPA reposity ?
Thanks!
ObjectEntity:

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import serverApp.classes.common.ObjectID;
import serverApp.classes.superapp.superappobject.Location;
import serverApp.classes.superapp.superappobject.CreatedBy;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.CreatedByConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.LocationConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.ObjectDetailsConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.ObjectIDConverter;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_TBL")
public class ObjectEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Convert(converter = ObjectIDConverter.class)
    private ObjectID objectId;

    private String type;
    private String alias;

    @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
    private Location location;
    private boolean active;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationTimestamp;

    @Convert(converter = CreatedByConverter.class)
    private CreatedBy createdBy;

    @Convert(converter = ObjectDetailsConverter.class)
    @Lob
    private Map<String, Object> objectDetails; // Changed to Map<String, Object>

    public ObjectEntity(Map<String, Object> objectDetails, CreatedBy createdBy, Date creationTimestamp, boolean active, Location location, String alias, String type, ObjectID objectId) {
        this.objectDetails = objectDetails;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
        this.active = active;
        this.location = location;
        this.alias = alias;
        this.type = type;
        this.objectId = objectId;
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public ObjectEntity() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ObjectID getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(ObjectID objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Date getCreationTimestamp() {
        return creationTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreationTimestamp(Date creationTimestamp) {
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
    }

    public CreatedBy getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(CreatedBy createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getObjectDetails() {
        return objectDetails;
    }

    public void setObjectDetails(Map<String, Object> objectDetails) {
        this.objectDetails = objectDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectEntity{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", objectId=" + objectId +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", alias='" + alias + '\'' +
                ", location=" + location +
                ", active=" + active +
                ", creationTimestamp=" + creationTimestamp +
                ", createdBy=" + createdBy +
                ", objectDetails=" + objectDetails +
                '}';
    }
}

Location class:

public  class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(double lat, double lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}```


Here is how you can achieve it:
You need to use AttributeOverride and Embedded on location in ObjectEntity.
Here how you can do it on your code
ObjectEntity class: 
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import serverApp.classes.common.ObjectID;
import serverApp.classes.superapp.superappobject.Location;
import serverApp.classes.superapp.superappobject.CreatedBy;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.CreatedByConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.LocationConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.ObjectDetailsConverter;
import serverApp.entities.superapp.convertors.ObjectIDConverter;

import jakarta.persistence.AttributeOverride;
import jakarta.persistence.Embedded;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECT_TBL")
public class ObjectEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Convert(converter = ObjectIDConverter.class)
    private ObjectID objectId;

    private String type;
    private String alias;

    @Convert(converter = LocationConverter.class)
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name = "location", column = @Column(name = "location"))
    private Location location;
    private boolean active;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date creationTimestamp;

    @Convert(converter = CreatedByConverter.class)
    private CreatedBy createdBy;

    @Convert(converter = ObjectDetailsConverter.class)
    @Lob
    private Map<String, Object> objectDetails; // Changed to Map<String, Object>

    public ObjectEntity(Map<String, Object> objectDetails, CreatedBy createdBy, Date creationTimestamp, boolean active, Location location, String alias, String type, ObjectID objectId) {
        this.objectDetails = objectDetails;
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
        this.active = active;
        this.location = location;
        this.alias = alias;
        this.type = type;
        this.objectId = objectId;
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public ObjectEntity() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ObjectID getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(ObjectID objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Date getCreationTimestamp() {
        return creationTimestamp;
    }

    public void setCreationTimestamp(Date creationTimestamp) {
        this.creationTimestamp = creationTimestamp;
    }

    public CreatedBy getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(CreatedBy createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getObjectDetails() {
        return objectDetails;
    }

    public void setObjectDetails(Map<String, Object> objectDetails) {
        this.objectDetails = objectDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ObjectEntity{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", objectId=" + objectId +
                ", type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", alias='" + alias + '\'' +
                ", location=" + location +
                ", active=" + active +
                ", creationTimestamp=" + creationTimestamp +
                ", createdBy=" + createdBy +
                ", objectDetails=" + objectDetails +
                '}';
    }
}

Location class:
public  class Location {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public Location() {
    }

    public Location(double lat, double lng) {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lng = lng;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }
}

Now to get the jpa query working, all you need to is to update the Repository in the following way:
List<ObjectEntity> findAllObjectsByLocation(Location location);

This will generate a query in the following way:
select <columns> from OBJECT_TBL where lat = ? and lng = ?


Thank you for your answer, but where does it get the radius as a parameter?
I needed to get all objects with location that is within the radius like I showed in the image attached. Your answer will get me a specific location I guess, isn't it?

do you have a radius as a column on object_tbl table?

No :) that is what I'm trying to do. Just get the objects by radius when the only thing they have is lat and lng.

you can do a query with where clause only on the columns that are there on the table. if you want to do some calculation with radius on it, then my suggestion is to achieve that by calculating the lat and lng with radius before you make a jpa query and define the parameters for the where clause. then you can pass the parameters to the where clause and use that (or) pull the data and do your calculation on top of it with radius.
